# SSIS 2008 sequence number

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

I have a requirement where the output file needs to be saved(dynamically) with the naming convention as FileName_YYY-MM-DD_FileNumber where file number is the sequence number. For example:-

```
     ABC_2009-01-01_001  
     ABC_2009-01-01_002
     ABC_2009-01-01_003 and so on
```

I am able to get the name part and date part using expression in .TXT connection but unable to get the sequence number part. I would appreciate if anyone could help me out with the solution.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use a package variable that starts with "1" and add one to it for each new file.

EDIT:  To populate the variable, one way is to use a script task that opens a `filesystemobject` and gets all the file names in the folder, parses them and figures out what is the highest sequence number.   Then just add one to that number and set the value of the variable to that.

And no, I don't have any code handy that does that.  You'll need to write it yourself.

Comment: Can you help me out with writing of variable? I believe variable must get  the highest sequence number from a file and then add 1 to that number. If no files are present than by default it must be 0

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "writing of variable".   What do you have so far?   What are you stuck on?

Comment: I created a variable which saves the output file with a desired name in a desired location :- @[User::LOCN]+"ABCD"+ "_"+ (DT_WSTR, 30)(DT_DBDATE)GETDATE() +".txt"....................I am stuck with sequence number part